# Spring web-flux side operation returning Mono<Void>

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
public interface RefreshTokenReactiveRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<RefreshToken, Long> {

Mono<RefreshToken> findByValue(String value);

}
```

The next metod is in the TokenService class.

```
public Mono<TokenPair> exchangeRefreshToken(String refreshTokenValue) {
  return refreshTokenReactiveRepository.findByValue(refreshTokenValue)
    .zipWhen(
        previousRefreshToken ->
            refreshTokenReactiveRepository.deleteById(previousRefreshToken.getId())
                .then(Mono.just("")),
        (previousRefreshToken, deleteResult) -> previousRefreshToken
    )
    .map(RefreshToken::getAccount)
    .flatMap(this::generateTokenPair);
 }
```

I want to execute `refreshTokenReactiveRepository.deleteById(previousRefreshToken.getId())` side operation which depends on previous mono result(`Mono<RefreshToken>`) and `returns Mono<Void>`. Then I want zipWhen return `Mono<RefreshToken>`.

I achieved this only by using `then` to replace returning `Mono<Void>` value:

```
refreshTokenReactiveRepository.deleteById(previousRefreshToken.getId())
                    .then(Mono.just(""))
```

So, are there any more clear ways to achieve this goal? What is the alternative for zipWhen in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the return value of the `deleteById` method, you don't need to use `zip`; here you're just interested in deleting the previous token from the repository if it was there, and returning it. Something like this should work:

```
public Mono<TokenPair> exchangeRefreshToken(String refreshTokenValue) {
    return refreshTokenReactiveRepository.findByValue(refreshTokenValue)
            .flatMap(previousRefreshToken ->
                refreshTokenReactiveRepository
                        .deleteById(previousRefreshToken.getId())
                        .thenReturn(previousRefreshToken.getAccount())
            )
            .flatMap(this::generateTokenPair);
}
```

You could make this simpler by adding a `deleteByValue` method on your repository; you'd delete the token in the datastore and get it back in a single database query.

Comment: Brian, thanks for answer! But no-arg variant of 'then' returns Mono<Void> so "combinator" in zipWhen will not be called, so the output of zipWhen will be Mono<Void>.

Comment: Could you update your question to decompose things a bit? It's hard to reason with it when we don't have the signatures for the custom methods you're using.

Comment: Ok, I will do it.

Comment: I've updated my answer - thanks for editing your question!